# what is use of hibernate.reveng.xml and i dont knows how to setup hibernate in my swing project?

Tags: java, xml, swing, hibernate

anyone give me solution that is details of my hibernate configuration

error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at com.patelplastic.masterDao.HibernateFactory.configureSessionFactory(HibernateFactory.java:84)
    at com.patelplastic.masterDao.HibernateFactory.buildIfNeeded(HibernateFactory.java:31)
    at com.patelplastic.masterDao.AbstractDao.<init>(AbstractDao.java:14)
    at com.patelplastic.masterDao.GroupInfoDao.<init>(GroupInfoDao.java:14)
    at com.patelplastic.masterDao.GroupInformation.main(GroupInformation.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Hibrnate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/billingsystemdevdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <mapping resource="GroupInfo.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

*.hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Aug 27, 2014 10:54:21 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.patelplastic.masterpojo.CategoryInformation" table="category_information" catalog="billingsystemdevdb">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="categoryCode" type="string">
            <column name="category_code" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="categoryDes" type="string">
            <column name="category_des" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="salesTransactions" table="sales_transaction" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="category_info_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.patelplastic.masterpojo.SalesTransaction" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.reveng.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

    <hibernate-reverse-engineering>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="account_info"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="category_information"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="company_info_master"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="expense_info"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="group_info"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="item_group_information"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="item_master_maintenance"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="payment"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="sales_tax_information"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="sales_transaction"/>
      <table-filter match-catalog="billingsystemdevdb" match-name="sub_sales_transaction"/>
    </hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

File Directory is :

```
project/src/hibernate.cfg.xml
project/src/package/*.hbm.xml
project/hibernate.reveng.xml
```

configuration code is :

```
private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

so give me solution i dont want error other time.

Comment: A hibernate.reveng.xml file can provide a finer degree of control of the reverse engineering process. In this file you can specify type mappings and table filtering.

Comment: put aside how to config hibernate, your current problem is you lost required jar: dom4j, this is dependented by hibernate, add it to your class path first!